# Does Mongoengine expose $min, $max field operators?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine, and would like to be able to use the [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min),[$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max) field operators (to perform conditional updates), but I'm unable to see how I can do this via the mongoengine interface.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/863

Answer (score 1):

After some digging into the MongoEngine source, I decided to try using the `__raw__` parameter to the `update()` method.  Using this I was able to make use of the `$min` field operator (contrived, working example):

`attribs.objects(name='Mag')[0].update(__raw__={'$min': {'min_value': 4.9}})`

This updates the `min_value` iff the value 4.9 is < the current value of `min_value`.

FWIW, I have opened [issue 863](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/863) on the MongoEngine githup repo
 requesting more direct access to the `$min` and `$max` field operators.